# Amazon S3 Datastores using Datanucleus

Tags: java, amazon-s3, datanucleus

From this link: https://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/datastores/datastores.html#amazons3

It seems it is possible to use S3 as data persistence using [Datanucleus](https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-json).

What are the capabilities that are supported for storing and querying Java Objects to/from S3 with Datanucleus? Do JDOQL works with the datastore?

Do query like this would work against the S3 as JSON datastore?

```java
Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM mydomain.Person WHERE lastName == 'Jones' && age < age_limit PARAMETERS int age_limit");
List<Person> results = (List<Person>)q.execute(20);
```